# Can't install Windows 7 on a laptop with NVidia GTX 1070

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, nvidia-graphics-card

I am having trouble installing Windows 7 on a new laptop.  This is a custom-built PC from CyberPower PC, and I chose their option to have a blank hard drive instead of letting them install Windows 10.

So, here's the problem...  I wasn't able to get any USB device (since I don't have a CD-ROM drive) to be recognized as bootable on the computer, no matter what I tried, except for a Linux installation USB.  So, I went ahead and installed it.  Upon configuring the GRUB, I was able force the computer to load the Windows 7 USB.  However, it froze during the boot cycle about 4 seconds in.  Long story short, I figured out that it was because of the graphics card being too new, since the 10 series of NVidia's latest new GPU's utilizes a brand new architecture.  I was eventually able to install Windows 10 onto the computer using the same method, since it didn't lock up upon loading.

I have tried EVERYTHING that I could think of to get this to install, from injecting NVidia's drivers into the installation ".wim" file, to installing it from Windows 10.  The furthest I have gotten is combining those 2 methods and getting setup to at least copy Windows 7 onto a partition.  It just won't boot after that.

EDIT:  Because I was unable to solve this issue, I decided to run Windows 7 inside a Virtual Machine on my Linux installation.  I definitely think that the issue was because of the graphics card, since NVidia switched to their new architecture, but thanks for trying to help anyways, everyone.

My system specs from Cyberpower's website, in case there is something that I missed:

- CPU: Intel® Core™ Processor i7-6700K 4.00GHZ 8MB Intel Smart Cache LGA1151 (Skylake)
- HD_M2SATA: 240GB Intel 540s Series M.2 SATA-III 6.0Gb/s SSD - 560MB/s Read & 480MB/s Write
- HDD: 2TB SAMSUNG M9T 5400RPM 32MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s Hard Drive
- KEYBOARD: Built-in Full-color Programmable backlight with Anti-Ghost Keyboard
- MEMORY: 16GB (8GBx2) DDR4/2133MHz SODIMM Memory
- MOTHERBOARD: Mobile Intel Z170 Chipset Mainboard
- NETWORK: Gigabit LAN 10/100/1000 (Built-in)
- NOTEBOOK: 15.6" UHD, (3840x2160) 4K G-SYNC eDP Wide View Angle w/ Programmable RGB Keyboard, HDMI 1.4, mini display Port 1.2, Li-Ion Battery & Universal AC Adapter
- OS: None - FORMAT HARD DRIVE ONLY
- SOUND: Sound by Dynaudior Support 7.1 channel SPDIF output
- SPEAKERS: Built-in 2x 2W speakers w/ subwoofer
- USB: Built-in 1x USB3.1 Type C Port + 3x USB3.0 Ports
- VIDEO: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1070 8GB GDDR5 (Pascal)
- WNC: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 (2x2) + BT4.1 M.2 type

Comment: Is there a reason you want Windows 7 instead of 10?

Comment: Your problems have nothing to do with your GPU.  Your likely creating the bootable USB incorrectly.

Comment: add USB 3 drivers to boot.wim: http://superuser.com/a/1087537/174557

Comment: I want the functionality of Windows 7, and I've had all too many bugs while working with 10.  I will be dual-booting, so I'll have both 7 and 10.  About the bootable USB, I tried every method of creation, INCLUDING Microsoft's own bootable USB creator.  Now, the USB 3 drivers definitely sounds promising, as the laptop only has 3 USB 3 ports on the side.  I'll try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: again, add USB drivers to boot.wim

Answer (score 1):

This problem is indeed due to the Windows 7 installer not having USB 3.0 drivers. I had the same problem with an Asus Zenbook a while back and I was able to install Windows 7 from a bootable USB stick after mounting the disc image and including the usb3.0 drivers in the .WIM file.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the USB 3.0 drivers did not work.  I have given up on this issue, and you can see my edit above for my compromise.

Comment: Please in specific detail, explain how to add the USB 3.0 driver to the image file.