# How do you install Windows drivers without having access to Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, drivers, intel-rst

I've been trying to fix my girlfriend's laptop, and her issue seemed to be pretty tough to tackle. I consistently receive the BSOD error:

> driver irql not less or equal (iastora.sys)

before I'm able to access her Windows 8 OS.

I was able to use a linux USB to save everything off her disk, and then tried removing windows altogether. When I attempt to reinstall windows, the message comes up, and I realize I'm an idiot and that drivers must not be part of the operating system, but must be sitting somewhere else in the BIOS.

Internet research has led me to believe it has something to do with either Intel Rapid Start Technology or Intel Smart Response technology, based on the error message in the .001 seconds of blue screen time I get. Everyone else who gets this error is able to boot up Windows and it doesn't happen right at startup, so diagnosing my symptoms is a little more challenging.

I went through everything in the bios, booting with windows recovery disk or in recovery mode (no explicit 'safe' mode on her HP model) and all options (including trying to reinstall Windows) are immediate BSODs with the same screen message.

I have basic CS knowledge and linux experience but my knowledge of the OSs and how they relate to drivers is a weakness, so perhaps someone can figure out where my knowledge is lacking or how I should be fixing this issue.

Point being, I want to install the missing driver properly so that I can let her use Windows. I could install Ubuntu (and it works fine) but that misses my goal of getting my girlfriend's computer to work again with Windows. I'm basically curious if there's any way to know if this is something I'd do through the bios or through a Linux temp use session via external disk.

Comment: During the installation process there is a point where you can supply the required drivers. You can also create your own ISO that already contains the drivers.  Have you tried to do either of those things?

Comment: I would suggest getting another hard drive, put it into her laptop, and try to install onto a new hard drive instead of her old one.  Also, have you tried to use any other install media?  Are you using a cd or USB?  If you are using USB, are you using USB3?  I've seen some odd results when trying to install windows using a USB3 drive.   Also, try turning off secure boot in the bios (this is on my default on many computers running windows 8) to see if you get different results.

Comment: iastora.sys = INtel SATA driver. Use DISM to add a newer intel sata driver to the boot.wim and replace the default boot.wim on usb flash drive with this modified one

Comment: @Richie086 I'm using USB 3.0, and I have indeed tried messing with secure boot

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have never heard of DISM, but I think that answer seems to be the best direct solution to my problem.

Comment: @Ramhound It looks like I'll be modifying the drivers on the USB stick from the answer from magicandre1981. I'm not getting far enough (or anywhere) into the installation process to supply drivers.

Comment: I posted [here an example how to add USB3 drivers to Win7](https://superuser.com/a/1087537/174557), use the same steps for adding the Intel driver.

Comment: I think Andres suggestion is your best bet.